# How to Optimize a Dictionary / Word List?

Tags: dictionary, cryptography, brute-force

I have a copy of a 4.09 GB wordlist / dictionary `crackstation.txt`. Just now the words and numbers are arranged in the usual order:

```
0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStT uUvVwWxXyYzZ
```

How do I rearrange the order to something like:

```
tTaAsShHwWiIoObBmMfFcCdDpPnNeEgGrRyYuUvVjJkKqQzZxX 1023985467
```

*This sequence gives the first letters of English words in order of popularity, from most popular (left) to least popular (right)*

Answer (score 1):

Using some tools like grep, sed, awk, & sort you can implement some answers from [this other site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75498/sort-using-custom-pattern). They include (if you wanted b then d then everything else normally):

Pull out lines in the order desired, starting with the first, then second, etc"

```
grep '^b' myfile > outfile
grep '^d' myfile >> outfile
grep -v '^b' myfile | grep -v '^d' | sort >> outfile
```

Add your custom "sort key" first, then sort, then remove it later:

```
sed -e 's/^b/0&/' -e t -e 's/^d/1&/' -e 't' -e 's/^/2/' |
sort |
sed 's/^.//'
```

The easiest looks to be:

> use a language such as Perl, Python or Ruby that lets you easily specify a custom sort function.

```
perl -e 'print sort {($b =~ /^[bd]/) - ($a =~ /^[bd]/) ||
     $a cmp $b} <>'
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sorted(sys.stdin.readlines(), key=lambda s: (0 if s[0]=="b" else 1 if s[0]=="d" else 2), s))'
```

Or try awk (no explanation given, YMMV):

```
sort myfile | awk '$0 ~ /^b/ || $0 ~ /^d/ {print} $0 !~ /^b/ && $0 !~ /^d/ { a[f++] = $0 } END { for (word = 0; word < f; word++) { print a[word] } }'
```